# USB communication port

Tags: java, c, usb, pic18, eeprom

I want to send data from PIC18F4550 to an EEPROM. The PIC is located on a development kit 
I want to send data from my PC to the PIC using (USB PORT COMMUNICATION). * not serial *

I'm looking for a good code example or tutorial about how this operation is performed using either C or Java languages

Comment: libusb is a popular means of interfacing to arbitrary USB devices; however how you do it specifically would depend on the program you have loaded into the PIC processor.

Comment: Libusb is a library used in C++? .. Can you tell me where to find a good example ?

Comment: It can be used with any language that can call external functions.  Without information about what is running on the PIC, there's not much to say.  Presumably you can google for examples as readily as I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.waitingforfriday.com/index.php/Building_a_PIC18F_USB_device

A good tutorial about building a generic HID for the PIC.

Answer (score 0):

A video here (with C++) www.youtube.com/watch?v=lNdBIeXwED8
An example (in spanish) http://ladelec.com/practicas/colaboradores/alfredo-rossini/593-como-aprender-a-usar-el-puerto-usb-con-pic-18f4550-y-visual-basic-60